# C# ClickOnce Application Can't Load DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, pjsip

I have a small application that includes two third-party DLLs, pjsipDll.dll and sipeksdk.dll.  Both of these DLLs are set to True for Copy Local.  When I publish the application and install it on a second computer running Windows 7, it loads the sipeksdk dll fine and then that dll tries to use something from pjsipDll and it errors out saying:

"Unable to load DLL 'pjsipDll.dll': The specified module could not be found."

If I install this clickonce deployment on my development computer it works fine.

I looked in the deployment directory in on both computers, both DLLs are present, all the files are the same.  On both systems I'm running as an administrator.

Any ideas on what I might be missing?

Thank you,
Stateful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's funny how you fix the problem after posting on StackOverflow.  It appears I was using incompatible builds of the DLLs.  I found an older version of each that were known to work together and everything started working.